# PDFsharp Ximage does not contain a constructor that contains 1 argument

Tags: c#, image, pdfsharp

I am trying to write an XImage function that reads an image from a given URL and it looks like:

```
    public static XImage FromURI(string uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        webResponse.Close();
        PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage ximg = new PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage(image);
        return new PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage(image);
    }
```

but I am getting an error on the line

```
        return new PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage(image);
```

It says:

```
XImage does not contain a constructor that contains 1 argument.
```

When I look at the XImage.cs file, it seems like it has a constructor that has 1 argument.

```
namespace PdfSharp.Drawing
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Defines an object used to draw image files (bmp, png, jpeg, gif) and PDF forms.
    //     An abstract base class that provides functionality for the Bitmap and Metafile
    //     descended classes.
    public class XImage : IDisposable
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage class.
        protected XImage();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the vertical resolution of the image.
        public virtual double VerticalResolution { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the horizontal resolution of the image.
        public virtual double HorizontalResolution { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the size in point of the image.
        public virtual XSize Size { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the height of the image in pixels.
        public virtual int PixelHeight { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the width of the image in pixels.
        public virtual int PixelWidth { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the height of the image in point.
        public virtual double PointHeight { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the width of the image in point.
        public virtual double PointWidth { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the height of the image.
        [Obsolete("Use either PixelHeight or PointHeight. Temporarily obsolete because of rearrangements for WPF. Currently same as PixelHeight, but will become PointHeight in future releases of PDFsharp.")]
        public virtual double Height { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the width of the image.
        [Obsolete("Use either PixelWidth or PointWidth. Temporarily obsolete because of rearrangements for WPF. Currently same as PixelWidth, but will become PointWidth in future releases of PDFsharp.")]
        public virtual double Width { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating whether image interpolation is to be performed.
        public virtual bool Interpolate { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the format of the image.
        public XImageFormat Format { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Tests if a file exist. Supports PDF files with page number suffix.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   path:
        //     The path to a BMP, PNG, GIF, JPEG, TIFF, or PDF file.
        public static bool ExistsFile(string path);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates an image from the specified file.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   path:
        //     The path to a BMP, PNG, GIF, JPEG, TIFF, or PDF file.
        public static XImage FromFile(string path);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Conversion from Image to XImage.
        public static XImage FromGdiPlusImage(Image image);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Under construction
        public void Dispose();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Disposes underlying GDI+ object.
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Implicit conversion from Image to XImage.
        public static implicit operator XImage(Image image);
    }
}
```

And even if I try to fix this file, it cannot be fixed because it has a [from metadata] label.

Comment: I haven't noticed any constructor with 1 parameter in metadata. Where's it? Most likely you need to use FromGdiPlusImage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The last line in the class is an implicit operator, not a constructor. This will convert the `Image` to `XImage` imlicitly i.e. without any data loss. You cannot create XImage from Image as you have done. You need to do it like:

```
 XImage xImage = new PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage();
 xImage = image;
 return xImage;
```

You can read about `implice` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to call a URL from localhost to use the FromURI function? Right now when I test it, it says the access is not permitted.

Comment: I did not get your question exactly. But are you able to access your input URL from browser?

Comment: it only works when I run my web on visual studio. the url looks like localhost/somethingsomething.. so it doesn't work on the pdf generator.

Comment: It seems that you have not created any website on your local IIS which maps to the code you have written, so it works only when Visual Studio is running (which it does in IISExpress while running). You can post another question with all required details, if this solution does not work for you.

Comment: The code snippet creates two `XImage` objects - the object from the first line is overwritten in the second line. `return (XImage)image;` should do it in just one line. But using `XImage.FromStream` mentioned in the other answer and avoiding the `Image` object completely is the better way.

Comment: My answer is to answer the question `When I look at the XImage.cs file, it seems like it has a constructor that has 1 argument.` . And not how we can optimize the memory/code. How `return (XImage)image` type conversion answers the question about error related to the constructor with one parameter?

Comment: The first line of your sample code calls the constructor without parameters to create an object that will be inaccessible as soon as the second line of code implicitly constructs a new object that is assigned to a variable to be returned by the third line of code. I condensed your three lines to a single line with the same effect: `return (XImage)image;` Much shorter and GC friendly. People ask questions to solve problems. The best solution for a problem at hand will sometimes deviate a bit from the question they ask.

Comment: The one line answer does not answer the confusion about error due to passing one parameter to the constructor. So even if you can solve the problem by other ways too, the person who is asking/seeking answer should know what he/she was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do: skip creating the `Image` and create the `XImage` directly from the stream.

The `XImage` class has some static members. There is `XImage.FromGdiImage` that takes an `Image` (this would be the answer to your question) and there is `XImage.FromStream` that avoids creating the `Image` in the first place.

When your project references PDFsharp DLLs (e.g. from NuGet) then Visual Studio will show you decompiled meta data that cannot be changed. You can use the PDFsharp source code, add references to the .csproj files and make changes es needed.
The constructor that takes an `Image` as parameter is not public. No need to make it public as you can use `XImage.FromGdiImage` to access it. Note that only the GDI build of PDFsharp has this method. When using the WPF build, you can use `XImage.FromStream`.